# Как отобразить количество товара в разных режимах работы со складом woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Возникла следующая проблема: при экспорте товаров через плагин, если включены запасы товара, то плагин берет значение с 'quantity' => $product->get_stock_quantity()

Как дописать, что если выключены запасы товара то должно быть вот так 'quantity' => $quantity ?: 999 ?

Comment: Куда дописать?  Как минимум ты должен указать плагин. Не помешает и детальней расписать свой процесс экспорта. В какой формат экспортируешь? Исправь вопрос. (и я не понял - нужно заменить null на 999? Серьёзно?)

Comment: 999 - это скорее всего что бы показать что товар всегда есть, если не отметили сколько осталось на складе. Ну к примеру мебель на заказ сам магазин делует... но да без описания как оно работает, тут помощи не будет.